# Twitter OAuth version

Tags: oauth, twitter

What is OAuth version in Twitter API? I don't found exactly version number in their documentaion. I found only reference to OAuth 1 specification. Does Twitter support OAuth 2 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter does not currently support OAuth 2.0 as the 2.0 spec is [still in draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15). The current version is 1.0a.